# What method is used to modified a property from an array of records returned from a Mongoose query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```js
    const images = await tbl
      .find({
        creator_id: req.user._id,
      })
      .select({
        creator_id: 0,
      })
      .then((images) =>
        images.forEach((image) => {
          image.file_name = process.env.IMAGE_HOST_URL + image.file_name;
        })
      );
```

The code above fails at the `.then` bit.
What is the proper mongoose method to replace it with to achieve what is intended in the code?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean fails?

The find returns two objects. An err and res.
the .then should be

```
.then((err, res) => {
    if (err) {...}
    else {
        res.forEach(img => {
           image.file_name = process.env.IMAGE_HOST_URL + image.file_name;
           img.save() 
        })
    }

})
```

You will get a list of documents that match the filter of the find as the res (error object, which should be null, is first). And you must save it after the changes.